# C incomplete type for struct

Tags: c

I am attempting to take RRhead, have a new RCB point at RRhead as it's next, and have RRhead point at the new RCB as it's prior.

```
typedef struct{
  int sequence_number;
  int file_descriptor;
  FILE *requested_file;
  int bytes_remaining;
  int quantum;
  struct RCB *next;
  struct RCB *prior;
} RCB;

typedef struct RCB RCB;


RCB *RRhead = NULL;


static void admit_to_scheduler_RR(int fd, FILE *fin){
int sequence_counter, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum = 0;
  RCB new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum, RRhead, NULL};
  RRhead->prior = &new_rcb;
  RRhead = &new_rcb;
  sequence_counter++;
}
```

producing the following errors:

```
sws.c: In function ‘admit_to_scheduler_RR’:
sws.c:318:10: error: variable ‘new_rcb’ has initializer but incomplete type
   struct RCB new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum, RRhead, NULL};
          ^
sws.c:318:10: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_rcb’) [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_rcb’) [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_rcb’) [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_rcb’) [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_rcb’) [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_rcb’) [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:10: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_rcb’) [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:14: error: storage size of ‘new_rcb’ isn’t known
   struct RCB new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum, RRhead, NULL};
              ^
sws.c:319:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   RRhead->prior = &new_rcb;
         ^
```

I have no clue about why I am getting the warnings for excess elements. Am I not initializing new_rcb correctly? Do I need to create it and then set all of the fields to what I want?

I believe this all has to do with having an "incomplete type" for new_rcb. Most googling indicates that this is because the compiler doesn't know what the size of RCB should be. It seems to indicate that I need to place this struct definition into a header. Is this absolutely necessary?

Comment: `typedef struct RCB RCB;` try removing that

Comment: Removing that causes different errors to occur in this function.

Answer (score 2):

In the first statement, you are declaring `RCB` to be a `struct` using `typedef`. Directly afterwards, you are saying, 'by the way, `RCB` means `struct RCB`', which is not defined at this point! (For that to exist, you'd have to say `struct RCB { ... };` instead.)

---

Basically,  delete the `typedef struct RCB RCB;` which will get rid of the related errors, but new ones will pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your struct to the following (i.e. remove the typedef keyword):

```
struct RCB {
  int sequence_number;
  int file_descriptor;
  FILE *requested_file;
  int bytes_remaining;
  int quantum;
  struct RCB *next;
  struct RCB *prior;
};
```

Further information can be read in this answer to [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/1566187).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
typedef struct RCB RCB;
strutc RCB {
 ....
```

The "tag" name space in C (coming with `struct` and `union`) is different from the identifier name space. With your typedef you also associate the identifier `RCB` to the the type `struct RCB`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct RCB RCB;

typedef struct RCB {
    int sequence_number;
    int file_descriptor;
    FILE *requested_file;
    int bytes_remaining;
    int quantum;
    RCB *next;
    RCB *prior;
} RCB;

RCB new_rcb = {11, 21, NULL, 31, 41, NULL, NULL};;

static void admit_to_scheduler_RR(int fd, FILE *fin) {

    int sequence_counter = 0;
    int new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum = 0;
    RCB *RRhead = &new_rcb;
    RRhead->prior = &new_rcb;
    sequence_counter++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    admit_to_scheduler_RR(1, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

To fix your errors, you need to change your code to something similar to the above, which uses your data structures and compiles.